# Error serializing value when databinding a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I am databinding a DropDownList using SelectedItem to display the value. Code is like this on the f/e:

```
DataTextField="client_name" DataValueField="client_ID" Enabled="False"
Width="200px"   SelectedItem='<%# Bind("BOND_CLIENT_DETAILS") %>'>
```

However when it load I get the following error:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error serializing value '(Please Select)' of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem.'

Any ideas? Much appreicated. This is driving me bats

Answer (score 0):

Change `SelectedItem` to `SelectedValue` and make sure you are binding the `client_ID` - `BOND_CLIENT_DETAILS` look suspiciously like it isn't the client_ID your looking for in the list.